# Static route in Centos 6

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

Here is my `route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

And if I try to add a static route by this command:

```
route add -net 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.50.1
```

I get the following output:

`SIOCADDRT: No such process`

Why that? Can anybody explain my the concept of adding static routes in linux.

If I also have a `route-eth0` file under the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory, with this line in it: `123.123.123.0/24 via 123.123.124.1`, no effect is achieved after I restart the network.

So, can anybody give me some explanations, links or related stuff to read on this?

Answer (score 2):

```
# ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.0/ via xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq
```

Is also valid syntax, but methinks that the error you are getting is a fouled up way of telling you:

`"cannot route  192.168.50.0 through 192.168.50.1, because i don't know how to get to 192.168.50.1 in the first place."`

Note that 192.168.50.1 is in the 192.168.50.0 network.

Comment: This answer is plausible, but I'd need artaxerxe to show his interface table (`ifconfig -a`) to be sure.

Comment: Look, if you had an (up) interface already configured on  192.168.50.0, you would not need to manually add routes, because it would already be there (ip route show) as a part of the interface  activation process. "ifconfig -a", of course, should tell the same story, as should "ip addr show". What is preventing you from running these commands?